# Any lightweight Linux/Cross-platform text editor that does tables?

Tags: linux

I like to organize info in tables. OpenOffice/LibreOffice is too heavyweight, I don't need the hit to swap nor the featureset. Is there any lightweight editor that does a table/grid like that, and can export to CSV?

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to start any flame, but Emacs can [handle tables](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode). I am not sure whether anyone would consider it lightweight, though.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know. I'm definitely not an emacs guy, but it may be worth it for me for this one feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a text editor that does that, the way I solve this problem is to use Google's spreadsheets. No need to any software, cross platform.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets